# Recyclerview on item selection with long click

Tags: android

I have recycler view and i parse data from jsonArray and display it as lists.now i want to highlight the row when I long click on a position i have already coded for long click.How to highlight the selected row.please help me with this.

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "long clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }));
```

Comment: You can store item-position and check in adapter if item-position match with your stored position then change item color..

Comment: see [Selecting Items of a RecyclerView using StateListDrawables](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/statelistdrawables-for-recyclerview-selection/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a class

```
public class RecyclerViewItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    //GestureDetector to detect touch event.
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private QueriesListFragment.ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerViewItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final QueriesListFragment.ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                //Find child on x and y position relative to screen
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        //On Touch event
        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildLayoutPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
```

Define a interface

```
public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);

    void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}
```

Assign this to recycler view

```
myRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerViewItemClickListener(getActivity(), mQueriesListRecyclerView, new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            //triggers when click
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
             //triggers when you long press
        }
    }));
```

Comment: Where are you connect with adapter

Answer (score 4):

I would try to add the `longClick listener` when you do the `onBindViewHolder` in your **adapter**.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(E holder, int position) {
    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // Do your stuff
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this. In your adapter, under OnBindViewHolder Method like:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return false;
           //todo to highlight the row
        }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case if you have the longClicked item position as `int` and item it self as `view` you can do that:

```
            recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new 

                RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view, int position) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                                    view.setTag("Selected"); 
                                    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(position);
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }));
```

Then in your `RecyclerView.Adapter` shuld do this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(YourViewHolderClass holder, int position) {
          if(holder.getTag().equals("Selected"){
                    //do highlight
                    //for example whit [RecyclerView.ItemDecoration][1]
                }else{
                    //remove highlight
                    //else is mandatory in order to prevent bugs when view is recycled
                }
    });
}
```