# How to use setOnLongClickListener on menu item in navigation drawer in Android?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, menuitem

`getActionView` always return null:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    item.getActionView().setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(), "Hello, World!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I don't wont use other layout, i want set long click on item.

Comment: Add on touch listener follow the post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46618738/4456860

Answer (score 0):

1. Inflate: View view = new​ View(this);
2. Set listener: view.setOnLongClickListener();
3. Set action view: menuItem.setActionView(view);

Comment: When i set view , my item do not look like I want :(

Comment: @superpuper Yeah, you are right. Also this code add view to the right of menuItem.

Comment: I also conducted a litle research and found that even if you can get access to menuItem view instance setting longclicklistener doesn't work.